# remove class from JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog, removeclass

using a div...

```
 $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog({
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        minHeight: "none",
        position: { my: "left"+ leftPosOfMessage + "% top+" + extraHeaderSize, at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
        show: { effect: "slideDown" },
        hide: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons:[],
        dialogClass: "alert",

    }).parent().appendTo("form:first");

    //populate text of label
    $('#popUpLabel').text(popUpMessage);

    //remove titleBar
    $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").siblings('div.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
```

I can remove the titleBar, but I would also like to remove the ui-widget-content class from the dialog.

//neither of these work

```
$("#saveDialogSingleFeature").siblings('ui-widget-content').remove();
$('saveDialogSingleFeature').removeClass("ui-widget-content");
```

any idea as to why

Comment: Did you mean `$('#saveDialogSingleFeature').removeClass("ui-widget-content"); `?

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
$('#saveDialogSingleFeature').removeClass("ui-widget-content");
```

The `remove` method will remove the entire element. I think you just missed the '#' to get the right element by id.

Comment: opps missed that wee typo...tried it out though but still not job. deleted cache and tried again but still the same. If I inspect element the ui-widget-content is still applied??

Answer (score 1):

Removing it from the parent done the trick

```
$('#saveDialogSingleFeature').parent().removeClass("ui-widget-content");
```